# States in TabStackNavigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

It seems like TabNavigator doesn't have it's own state. Is there any way to use `state` or `props`?

I want to show `the number of unread notification` on the Notification TabIcon.

```
export default TabNavigator(
  {
    ...
    Noti: {
      screen: NotificationStackNavigator,
    },
    ...
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      header: null,
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let iconName;
        switch (routeName) {
          ...
          case 'Noti':
            iconName = 'ios-notifications';
            break;
          ...
        }
        ...
        if(iconName == 'ios-notifications') {
          return (
            <IconBadge
              MainElement={
                <Ionicons
                  name={iconName}
                  size={30}
                  style={{ marginBottom: -3 }}
                  color={focused ? Colors.tabIconSelected : Colors.tabIconDefault}/>
              }
              BadgeElement={
                <Text style={{color:'#FFFFFF'}}>
                    {{this.state.notifications}} // my goal
                </Text>
              }
              IconBadgeStyle={{
                backgroundColor: '#f64e59',
                position: 'absolute',
                right:-10,
                top:0,
                }}
            />
          );
        }
        ...
```

Please let me know if anything is unclear. Thanks in advance

**UPDATE** I'm planning to refactor my TabNavigator. Is this what you're trying to say?

```
export default TabNavigator( 

to 

const MainTabNavigator = TabNavigator(

class MainTabNavigator extends Component {
    state = {notification}

export default connect(...)(MainTabNavigator);
```

**UPDATE 2** MainTabNavigator's Top Level component is another TabNavigator. Is there any other solution?

```
const RootTabNavigator = TabNavigator ({
    Auth: {
      screen: AuthStackNavigator,
    },
    Welcome: {
      screen: WelcomeScreen,
    },
    Main: {
      screen: MainTabNavigator,
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass additional custom props via `screenprops`

```
const TabNav = TabNavigator({
  // config
});

<TabNav
  screenProps={/* this prop will get passed to the screen components as this.props.screenProps */}
/>
```

The full documentation is [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't think you understand my question. I want to use state and props in TabNavigator where you comment as `//config`. And sorry your example code doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Well `TabNavigator` is stateless so no you don't get state, but you do get props. In your config, you can refer to `this.props.myCustomProp` and when you render, to  `<TabNav myCustomProp='Some value set on the parent' />`

Comment: I hope this is not true. I have no way to track of `how many unread notification the user have`

Comment: Well why not? Just have the state living on the component above (the app) and pass the value as a prop to this stateless component..

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to say. Can you check edited **UPDATE** code?

Comment: like on the example [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/) you should have a top level component that renders `TabNavigator`, this should be where you import `TabNavigator`

Comment: MainTabNavigator's Top Level component is another TabNavigator. **UPDATE2**

Comment: I think you can solve this problem (+200 bounty) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47930049/how-to-reset-tabnavigator-when-user-logs-out-from-other-screen